# Not able to call Sanitize method from javascript in Android 4.4 as same is working in Android 4.1

Tags: c#, android, webview, xamarin.android, android-4.4-kitkat

Not able to call Sanitize method from javascript in Android 4.4 where as same is working in Android 4.1. we can call Sanitize method from android 4.1 like Foo.sanitize('test message') where as same is not working in 4.4. Can someone please try to resolve how to call sanitize method.
if we add [Export] & [JavascriptInterface] again its working but ideally no need to these annotations to call sanitize.

```
 using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Webkit;
using Java.Interop;
using Android.Net;

namespace WebViewJavaScriptInterface
{

[Activity (Label = "Mono WebView ScriptInterface", MainLauncher = true)]
public class JavaScriptInterfaceActivity : Activity
{
const string html = @"<html><body><p>This is a paragraph.</p><button type=""button"" onClick=""Foo.sanitize('test message')"">Click Me!</button></body></html>";

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);

        WebView view = FindViewById<WebView> (Resource.Id.web);
        view.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        view.SetWebChromeClient (new WebChromeClient ());
        view.AddJavascriptInterface ((Java.Lang.Object)new Foo (this), "Foo");
        view.LoadData (html, "text/html", null);
    }
}

class Foo : Java.Lang.Object, UrlQuerySanitizer.IValueSanitizer
{
    public Foo (Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    Context context;

     [Export]
     [JavascriptInterface]
    public void Bar (string  message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("Foo.Bar invoked!");
        Toast.MakeText (context, "This is a Toast from C#! " + message.ToString(), ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }

    public string Sanitize(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Santizie.Bar invoked!");
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does there any error on 4.4? Have you tried it on other 4.4 phone?

Comment: I am getting below error -[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bar'", source: data:text/html,<html><body><p>This is a paragraph.</p><button type="button" onClick="Foo.bar('test message')">Click Me!</button></body></html> (1)
05-05 19:18:44.069 I/chromium(16397): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bar'", source: data:text/html,<html><body><p>This is a paragraph.</p><button type="button" onClick="Foo.bar('test message')">Click Me!</button></body></html> (1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'bar'"

The method should be `Bar`, not `bar`.

Please change your `html` to this:

```
const string html = @"
<html><body><p>This is a paragraph.</p><button type=""button"" onClick=""Foo.Bar('test message')"">Click Me!</button></body></html> 
";
```

Comment: Thank you so much Joe Lv. It worked.But, Santize is not getting called when we call from html. Always we are getting Object [object Object] has no method 'sanitize' in Android 4.4 where as it worked very well in Android 4.1

Comment: By `Santize`, have you added another method? Could you please edited your question?

Comment: Hello, you have forgot add `[Export] [JavascriptInterface]` for your `Sanitize`, method and you also need capital `S` in your `html`

Comment: As per android documentation, if we want two way communication we can make use of Sanitize from UrlQuerySanitizer.IValueSanitizer. Santize method is working when we test the program in Android 4.1 but same code is not working in Android 4.4. If we keep those 2 (Export, JavaScriptInterface) annotations we could able to call the method. But my question is why Santize alone is not working Android 4.4 which is working in Android4.1